# When using the NextJS Link and next/script the Script doesn't load when a navigation occurs. But it works with <a> tag

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm working on an App that needs to load the "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" api, I used the Script component of NextJS, when try to navigate using the Link from NextJS, the script doesn't load again. But if enter the url directly on the browser it fetch and load everything. I don't know why the Link is not working properly.

The Script is on a ReactContext that manages the load of the Google script.

This is the Context and context provider

```
import { googleGsiClient } from '@/utils';
import Script from 'next/script';
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export interface IGoogleSignInContext {
  scriptLoaded: boolean;
  scriptError?: string;
}

export const GoogleSignInContext = createContext<IGoogleSignInContext>({
  scriptLoaded: false,
});

export const GoogleSignInProvider: React.FC<{
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}> = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<IGoogleSignInContext>({
    scriptLoaded: false,
  });

  const handleScriptLoaded = () => {
    console.log('GOOGLE SCRIPT LOADED')
    setState((actual) => ({
      ...actual,
      scriptLoaded: true,
    }));
  };

  const handleScriptError = () => {
    setState((actual) => ({
      ...actual,
      scriptLoaded: false,
      scriptError: 'Failed to load script',
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('MOUNTING THE GOOGLE PROVIDER');
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <GoogleSignInContext.Provider value={state}>
        <Script
          src={googleGsiClient}
          onLoad={handleScriptLoaded}
          onError={handleScriptError}
        />
        {children}
      </GoogleSignInContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```

This is my google button Component

```
import { GoogleSignInContext } from '@/context/GoogleSignIn'
import { GoogleCredentialResponse } from '@/interfaces';
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export interface GoogleSignInButtonProps {
  onSingIn?: (credentials: GoogleCredentialResponse) => void;
  calcWidth: number | null;
}

export const GoogleSignInButton: React.FC<GoogleSignInButtonProps> = ({
  onSingIn,
  calcWidth
}) => {

  const googleContext = useContext(GoogleSignInContext);
  const buttonRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    
    if(!googleContext.scriptLoaded) return;
    console.log(calcWidth);
    if(!buttonRef) return;
    if(!calcWidth) return;

    window.google?.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENTID,
      callback(credentialResponse: GoogleCredentialResponse) {
          onSingIn?.(credentialResponse);
      },
    });

    window.google?.accounts.id.renderButton(buttonRef.current!, {
      type: 'standard',
      shape: 'rectangular',
      size: 'large',
      theme: 'outline',
      locale: "en_US",
      width: calcWidth.toString(),
    })

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [googleContext.scriptLoaded, calcWidth, buttonRef])

  if(!googleContext.scriptLoaded || !calcWidth) return <></>;

  return (
    <div ref={buttonRef} id='google-button' style={{height: 45}}></div>
  )
}
```

My login and register are different pages. So i can nagivate between those with the Link

Portion of code in Login to navigate to register

```
          <div className="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-around">
            <small>Don&apos;t have an account?</small>
            <small>
              <Link href={"/auth/register"} prefetch={false}>Create account</Link>
              
              {/* eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-html-link-for-pages */}
              {/* <a href='/auth/register'>Sign In</a> */}
            </small>
          </div>
```

Portion of code in Register to navigate to login

```
              <div className="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-around">
                <small>Already have an account? </small>
                <small>
                  <Link href={'/auth'} prefetch={false}>Sign In</Link>
                  {/* eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-html-link-for-pages */}
                  {/* <a href='/auth'>Sign In</a> */}
                </small>
              </div>
```

How can I use the NextJS Link and make the load of the script working? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, another way more straightforward is to use the onReady handler of the Script component, is called everytime the component is mounted and the script loaded

This works, when navigation occurs it calls the onReady and the script is already to use

```
import { googleGsiClient } from '@/utils';
import Script from 'next/script';
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export interface IGoogleSignInContext {
  scriptLoaded: boolean;
  scriptError?: string;
}

export const GoogleSignInContext = createContext<IGoogleSignInContext>({
  scriptLoaded: false,
});

export const GoogleSignInProvider: React.FC<{
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}> = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<IGoogleSignInContext>({
    scriptLoaded: false,
  });

  const handleScriptLoaded = () => {

  };

  const handleScriptError = (e: any) => {
    console.log(e);
    setState((actual) => ({
      ...actual,
      scriptLoaded: false,
      scriptError: 'Failed to load script',
    }));
  };

  const handleOnReady = () => {
    setState((actual) => ({
      ...actual,
      scriptLoaded: true,
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('MOUNTING THE GOOGLE PROVIDER 2');
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <GoogleSignInContext.Provider value={state}>
        <Script
          key={'google-gsi-script'}
          id="google-gsi-script"
          src={googleGsiClient}
          onLoad={handleScriptLoaded}
          onError={handleScriptError}
          onReady={handleOnReady}
          async
          defer
        />
        {children}
      </GoogleSignInContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: how would I apply this to a basic javascript? I'm using owl-carousel, how would I use this technique for that?

Answer (score 0):

I've already found a solution, when the page is loaded for the first time, it fetch the script but then the script remain in the document no matter if you do navigation between pages. So in the context that manage the script I added a patch for check if the script is in the document when component is mounted, and do not load the Script component if exist because it causes some strange behaviour. This is my context now

```
import { googleGsiClient } from '@/utils';
import Script from 'next/script';
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export interface IGoogleSignInContext {
  scriptLoaded: boolean;
  scriptError?: string;
}

export const GoogleSignInContext = createContext<IGoogleSignInContext>({
  scriptLoaded: false,
});

export const GoogleSignInProvider: React.FC<{
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}> = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<IGoogleSignInContext>({
    scriptLoaded: true,
  });

  const handleScriptLoaded = () => {
    if (state.scriptLoaded) return; //already in document

    console.log('GOOGLE SCRIPT LOADED');
    setState((actual) => ({
      ...actual,
      scriptLoaded: true,
    }));
  };

  const handleScriptError = (e: any) => {
    console.log(e);
    setState((actual) => ({
      ...actual,
      scriptLoaded: false,
      scriptError: 'Failed to load script',
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('MOUNTING THE GOOGLE PROVIDER');
    const gsiScript = document.getElementById('google-gsi-script');

    if (gsiScript) {
      console.log('GSI SCRIPT ALREADY LOADED', gsiScript);
      setState((actual) => ({
        ...actual,
        scriptLoaded: true,
      }));
    } else {
      setState((actual) => ({
        ...actual,
        scriptLoaded: false,
      }));
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <GoogleSignInContext.Provider value={state}>
        {!state.scriptLoaded ? (
          <Script
            key={'google-gsi-script'}
            id="google-gsi-script"
            src={googleGsiClient}
            onLoad={handleScriptLoaded}
            onError={handleScriptError}
            async
            defer
          />
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
        {children}
      </GoogleSignInContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [imart302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11595744/imart302) very much for the thread and the responses.
They have helped me understand the error I was having in an npm module that I'm developing for NextJS with Typescript.
In the end, I discovered that the error occurred because when using Link instead of "a" tag in my NextJS components, the pages would preload the external script but wouldn't launch or execute the code.
It wasn't possible to remove that preloaded script or reload it because it caused an error.

Thanks to this thread, I found a solution that works for me. Simply using useEffect, I check if the script is in the DOM. If it's not, I load it (for pages that don't use Link or are directly accessed). If it is, instead of loading it, I call a function included in the script to activate the logic. And it works for me, so I can continue using Link. :)
I hope this is useful to you if you have the same problem!

This is the code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log('We are mounting the CookieConsent component')
    const ccmScript = document.getElementById('cookie-consent-manager')

    if (ccmScript) {
      //console.log('ccmScript is been loaded', ccmScript)
      // we are going to launch a function inside /cookieconstent
      const inlineScript = document.createElement('script')
      inlineScript.innerHTML = `myCookieModal();`
      document.head.appendChild(inlineScript)
    } else {
      //console.log('ccmScript is not been loaded or not in the DOM', ccmScript)
      // we are going to add /cookieconstent to the DOM
      const script = document.createElement('script')
      script.src = '/cookieconsent.js'
      script.id = 'cookie-consent-manager'
      document.body.appendChild(script)
    }
  }, [])
```

If you want to see the repository is here:
https://github.com/CiroArtigot/nextjs-cookie-consent-manager

Comment: Hey, it's good to hear that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `react-helmet` solves the issue. like

```
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'

const MyScript: React.FC = () => (
    <Helmet>
      <script
        defer
        src="the script"
        type="text/javascript"
      />
    </Helmet>
)

export default MyScript
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Here is my solution if you want to keep the prefetching feature when navigating with the Link component while still loading the scripts every time the route changes :

1. **Use inline scripts:**

   `<Script src="/file.js"/>`

   Should be replaced by:

   `<Script>//your code here</Script>`
2. **Use var only**. As the script would already have been loaded when navigating  because of prefecthing (no reload of page), **do not use let or const**, for exemple:

   `<Script>var message = "hello world"</Script>`
3. This is not enough for production, you might get a build error if you do not **specify an id for your script**. But, this id must be random otherwise it will be considered as already added to the document. You can use `Math.random()` or something else to generate a random id. Here is a working script component:

   `` <Script id={`${ Math.random()}`}>var message = "hello world"</Script> ``

Hope it helps!